# Fragments e como passar infromações de activitys para elas

Tags: android

Tenho que passar um array adapter de string de uma activity, que é onde meu banco está carregando para uma fragment, onde quero setar isso em uma lista, mas nada que tento da certo. Alguém teria alguma ideia?

---

```
   // Banco

    try{
        database=new DataBase(this);

        conn = database.getWritableDatabase();

        res = new Repositorio(conn);
        res.testeinserir();


        // esse adpter recebe a lista vindo do banco 
        this.adpter = res.ListContas(this);


        Toast.makeText(this, "Conexão feita com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Erro ao se conectar ao banco!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

     //Aqui é onde mando a lista para o metodo setar lista que ta dentro da Classe Contas, que eu instanciei como adp  

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(adp != null){
                        adp.SetarLista(adpter);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
```

// Aqui é onde a lista é setada com o adpter, dentro da classe contas
    public void SetarLista(ArrayAdapter adpter){
        this.lista_contas .setAdapter(adpter);
    }

Comment: Poderia postar o que já tentou?

Comment: olha a baixo minha mais recente tentativa, mas ja tentei atravez do bundle ou até mesmo setar buscando o id do listView , se tiver alguma ideia... mas desde já agradeço

Comment: @BM_DNS, primeiramente você não teve fazer a conexão ao banco assim direto da activity, aconselho criar uma classe responsável para isso. Segue exemplo: https://goo.gl/BDXCS8.

Com isso você pode buscar onde quiser tanto na activity quanto no fragment, mas se quiser buscar na activity e passar ao fragment use o padrão para passagem de parâmetros a fragments.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17436739/5140172

Comment: @EzequielMessore usuário errado, **Obs.** Quem faz a pergunta sempre recebe nofificação, não é necessário menção

Comment: @BM_DNS opa foi mals nao sabia disso ... vlw pelo toque.

Comment: @EzequielMessore de boas, acontece

Comment: Vlew cara, ajudou muito ... realmente não sabia que não era bom carregar na activity... To meio que iniciando os estudos, muito obrigado ajudou muito!!!

Comment: Mas aqui, tem como passar um ArrayAdapter pelo bundle??

Answer (score 0):

Crie um Adapter customizado e implemente a interface Serializable. Para usar em ListView eu utilizo o Base Adapter:

```
public class MeuAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Serializable
```

Dessa forma, será possível passar a instancia desse Adapter pelo Bundle com `putSerializable("meuAdapter", meuAdapter)`.